# integrating Orbeon form with REST backend

Tags: orbeon

I'm trying to integrate Orbeon with a backend REST API (web application I just developed for testing purposes as we are evaluating Orbeon for a new project). I have followed the scenario mentioned on this tutorial http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api#TOC-A-scenario
and I have set my local properties (properties-local.xml) as following:

```
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
<property
            as="xs:string"
            name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.TestApp.WelcomeForm.data"
            value="coffee"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.coffee.uri" value="http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/coffee"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.coffee.active" value="true"/> 
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.coffee.autosave" value="false"/> 
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.coffee.permissions" value="false"/>     
</properties>
```

however, when I open my form in the form runner, I got Error message "Error performing search", and If I try to save a new form, I get the following message "There was an error communicating with the database. Please contact the application administrator."

Is there any tutorial shows how to integrate external REST backend service with Orbeon instead of a database (We want to use our backend REST services as persistence layer).